# Why don't these objects get GC'd?

Tags: python

From Python3 console:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 17:55:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.54)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 1.23
>>> b = a
>>> id(a)
4457705664
>>> id(b)
4457705664
>>> b = 5 # new object assigned to b
>>> id(b)
4456877312
>>> a = 5 # new object assigned to a?
>>> id(a)
4456877312
>>> a = 1.23 # should be a new object?
>>> id(a)
4457705664
```

So, my question here is hopefully pretty obvious. The ID of *a* changes when it is assigned to a new value, but when I reassign the value 1.23, the ID actually changes back to what it was originally. How does that work? My assumption is that once the *object* 1.23 had lost its references, it would be GC'd. Is this some kind of interpreter optimization or something?

Comment: This question is not really a duplicate, as far as I can tell. The question you refer to concerns two *different* floats being assigned the same id. This question talks about the same float not being garbage collected.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is an implementation detail of the  garbage collector. There is nothing forcing the garbage collector to run. If you interleave `import gc ; gc.collect()` after having re-assigned `a`, the float `1.23` gets garbage collected. Interestingly, the behaviour is different in python 2.7.

Comment: Thanks @PascalBugnion! That is what I was curious about.